# мне нужно cделать запрос с моего бэкенда nest.js на сторонний API где сервер написан на graphql

Tags: api, http, axios, nestjs, graphql

мне нужно делать запрос с моего бэкенда nest.js (он базируется на axios) на сторонний API где сервер написан на graphql, прочитал много информации по nest.js и graphql - везде написано как сделать свой сервер graphql

мне нужно просто понять какой синтаксис этого post запроса и всё, без всяких премудростей